# do.call in combination with "::"

Tags: r

I make a lot of use of 'do.call' to generate function calls. E.g:

```
myfun <- "rnorm";
myargs <- list(n=10, mean=5);
do.call(myfun, myargs);
```

However, sometimes I would like to call a function explicitly from a certain package. Similar to e.g. `stats::rnorm(n=10, mean=5)`. Is there any way I can use do.call, or create a function that behaves just like do.call to get this to work:

```
myfun <- "stats::rnorm";
myargs <- list(n=10, mean=5);
do.call(myfun, myargs);
```

Comment: how about `do.call(stats::rnorm, myargs)`?

Comment: @kohske - then it seems `stats::rnorm(n=10, mean=5)` is even simpler :-)

Comment: but in that case you cannot use list as its argument :-(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no function called "stats::rnorm". You must find the `rnorm` function in the "stats" namespace:

```
myfun <- get("rnorm", asNamespace("stats"))
myargs <- list(n=10, mean=5);
do.call(myfun, myargs);
```

Now you can of course also go from a name like "stats::rnorm" and split it into the namespace part and the function name:

```
funname <- "stats::rnorm"
fn <- strsplit(funname, "::")[[1]]
myfun <- if (length(fn)==1) fn[[1]] else get(fn[[2]], asNamespace(fn[[1]]))
myargs <- list(n=10, mean=5);
do.call(myfun, myargs);
```

**Update** I just wanted to show that this approach is 2.5x faster than the one from @Jeroen...

```
do.call.tommy <- function(what, args, ...) {
  if(is.character(what)){
    fn <- strsplit(what, "::")[[1]]
    what <- if(length(fn)==1) {
        get(fn[[1]], envir=parent.frame(), mode="function")
    } else {
        get(fn[[2]], envir=asNamespace(fn[[1]]), mode="function")
    }
  }

  do.call(what, as.list(args), ...)
}

# Test it
do.call.tommy(runif, 10)
f1 <- function(FUN) do.call.tommy(FUN, list(5))
f2 <- function() { myfun<-function(x) x; do.call.tommy(myfun, list(5)) }
f1(runif)
f1("stats::runif")
f2()

# Test the performance...    
system.time(for(i in 1:1e4) do.call.jeroen("stats::runif", list(n=1, max=50))) # 1.07 secs
system.time(for(i in 1:1e4) do.call.tommy("stats::runif", list(n=1, max=50)))  # 0.42 secs
```

Answer (score 17):

You can remove the quotes: that will be the function itself, rather than its name.

```
myfun <- stats::rnorm
myargs <- list(n=10, mean=5)
do.call(myfun, myargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I think I am going for something like this:

```
do.call.jeroen <- function(what, args, ...){
  if(is.function(what)){
    what <- deparse(as.list(match.call())$what);
  }
  myfuncall <- parse(text=what)[[1]];
  mycall <- as.call(c(list(myfuncall), args));
  eval(mycall, ...);
}
```

That seems to be a nice generalization of `do.call` so that I can still pass on a character string for the `what` argument, yet it neatly emulates a `stats::rnorm(n=10, mean=5)` call.

```
myfun1 <- "rnorm";
myfun2 <- "stats::rnorm";
myargs <- list(n=10, mean=5);
do.call.jeroen(myfun1, myargs);
do.call.jeroen(myfun2, myargs);
do.call.jeroen(rnorm, myargs);
do.call.jeroen(stats::rnorm, myargs);
```

One thing that is nice about this is that if the function that I am calling uses match.call() to store the call somewhere, it will preserve the actual function name. E.g:

> do.call.jeroen("stats::glm", list(formula=speed~dist, data=as.name('cars')))

```
Call:  stats::glm(formula = speed ~ dist, data = cars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         dist  
     8.2839       0.1656  

Degrees of Freedom: 49 Total (i.e. Null);  48 Residual
Null Deviance:      1370 
Residual Deviance: 478  AIC: 260.8
```

Comment: I don't really love the fact that you resort to `deparse`, `parse` and `eval` to solve this. For one, it doesn't handle `f<-function(x) do.call.jeroen(x, list(n=10)); f(runif)`, and it's more than twice as slow as calling `do.call`... I updated my answer with an alternative.

Comment: Thanks. I also updated my response a bit. One thing that I like about `do.call.jeroen` is that the original function name remains preserved, instead of replacing it with an anonymous function.